# Tratamento de exceções da base de dados

Tags: java, jpa, exceção

Como tratar exceções de bancos de dados com JPA?
E, como usar anotações no lugar da interface IMessage, como abaixo?

Exemplo:

1. Minha base de dados retorna o erro: "Violation constraint uk_email";
2. Pegar a constraint da mensagem de erro (uk_email) e procura na mesma base ou em outra uma mensagem correspondente a ela.

Minha solução, até agora:

- Interface

  ```
  package br.com.handlingjpa;

  /**
  * Interface usada para identificar qual &eacute; a classe de entidade que
  * representa a tabela de mensagens
  * 
  * @author Thiago Santos <thiprogramador@hotmail.com>
  * 
  */
  public interface IMessage {

      /**
       * Obt&eacute; o nome da constraint encontrada
       * 
       * @return A constraint encontrada
       */
      String getConstraint();

      /**
       * Defini qual foi a constraint encontrada na exce&ccedil;&atilde;
       * 
       * @param constraint O nome da constraint
       */
      void setConstraint(String constraint);

      /**
       * Obt&eacute; a mensagem referente a contraint
       * 
       * @return A mensagem
       */
      String getMessage();

      /**
       * Determina qual &eacute; a mensagem referente a constraint
       * 
       * @param message  A mensagem
       */
      void setMessage(String message);

      /**
       * Obt&eacute; a express&atilde;o regular que determina como encontrar uma
       * constraint
       * 
       * @return A express&atilde;o regular
       */
      String getRegex(); 

  }
  ```
- Handling exception class

  ```
  /*
   * Copyright (c) 2014. All rights reserved. 
   */
  package br.com.handlingjpa;

  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import java.util.regex.Matcher;
  import java.util.regex.Pattern;

  import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
  import javax.persistence.Query;

  /**
   * <p>
   * A classe <code>HandlingDBException</code> &eacute; utilizada para tratar
   * erros gerado pela base de dados. A mesma busca na exce&ccedil;&atilde;o (a
   * resposta dada pela base de dados do ocorrido) por um identificador do erro.
   * Ao encontrar-lo, a classe realiza uma consulta em busca da mensagem
   * correspondente.
   * </p>
   * 
   * @author Thiago Santos <thiprogramador@hotmail.com>
   * 
   */
  public class HandlingDBException {

      /**
       * A classe de entidade que faz refer&ecirc;ncia a tabela de mensagens
       */
      private IMessage entityClass;
      /**
       * O nome da <code>NamedQuery</code> usada para consulta
       */
      private String namedQuery;
      /**
       * O nome do par&acirc;metro na <code>NamedQuery</code> usado como filtro
       */
      private String paramName;

      /**
       * Cria um HandlingDBException e determina quem &eacute; a classe de
       * entidades, o nome da NamedQuery e o identificador do par&acirc;metro na
       * NamedQuery
       * 
       * @param entityClass A <b>inst&acirc;ncia</b> da classe de entidade. Ex: <code>new Entidade()</code>
       * @param namedQuery O nome da NamedQuery de consulta
       * @param paramName O identificador do par&acirc;metro na NamedQuery
       */
      public HandlingDBException(IMessage entityClass, String namedQuery,
              String paramName) {
          this.entityClass = entityClass;
          this.namedQuery = namedQuery;
          this.paramName = paramName;
      }

      /**
       * Busca uma mensagem com base em um erro enviado pela base de dados. Caso
       * encontre, ser&aacute; adicionado a entidade a constraint encontrada e a
       * mensagem correspondente a ela. Caso contr&aacute;rio, ser&aacute;
       * retornado a entidade do jeito que foi passada no construtor
       * 
       * @param exception Um Throwable com a exce&ccedil;&atilde;o
       * @param connection A conex&atilde;o que diz onde executar a consulta
       * @return Retorna a pr&oacute;pria entidade passada no construtor
       */
      public IMessage getMessageFromDatabase(Throwable exception,
              EntityManager connection) {
          // Busca por uma SQLException ou ate que seja null
          while (exception != null && !(exception instanceof SQLException)) {
              exception = exception.getCause();
          }
          // Verifica se e uma SQLException
          if (exception instanceof SQLException) {
              SQLException ex = (SQLException) exception;
              // Monta a regex de constraint
              Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(entityClass.getRegex());
              // Procura a ocorrencia na mensagem de erro
              Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ex.getMessage());
              // Verifica se achou alguma constraint
              if (matcher.find()) {
                  // Obtem a constraint no meio da mensagem
                  String constraint = ex.getMessage().substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                  entityClass.setConstraint(constraint);
                  // Busca a mensagem na base de dados
                  Query query = connection.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
                  query.setParameter(paramName, constraint);
                  String message = (String) query.getSingleResult();
                  entityClass.setMessage(message);
              }
          }
          return entityClass;
      }
  }
  ```
- Entity Class

  ```
  package br.com.handling.modelo;

  import javax.persistence.Column;
  import javax.persistence.Entity;
  import javax.persistence.Id;
  import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
  import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
  import javax.persistence.Table;

  import br.com.handlingjpa.IMessage;

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "tb_mensagem")
  @NamedNativeQuery(
                    name = "findMensagemFunction",
                    query = "SELECT dbo.uf_buscar_mensagem(:constraint)")
  @NamedQuery(
              name = "findMensagemQuery",
              query = "SELECT m.message FROM Mensagem m WHERE m.constraint = :constraint")
  public class Mensagem implements IMessage {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "tx_constraint")
      private String constraint;

      @Column(name = "tx_mensagem")
      private String message;

      public Mensagem() {

      }

      @Override
      public String getConstraint() {
          return this.constraint;
      }

      @Override
      public void setConstraint(String constraint) {
          this.constraint = constraint;
      }

      @Override
      public String getMessage() {
          return this.message;
      }

      @Override
      public void setMessage(String message) {
          this.message = message;
      }

      @Override
      public String getRegex() {
          return "(?i)([pfuc]k_\\w+)";
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
          final int prime = 31;
          int result = 1;
          result = prime * result
                  + ((constraint == null) ? 0 : constraint.hashCode());
          return result;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
          if (obj instanceof Mensagem) {
              Mensagem msg = (Mensagem) obj;
              if (msg.getConstraint() != null) {
                  return msg.getConstraint().equals(this.getConstraint());
              }
          }
          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return this.getMessage();
      }    
  }
  ```
- Main class

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      EntityManager em = // A conexão

      Teste t = new Teste();
      t.setId(2);
      t.setEmail("arjenrobben@holland.nl");

      try {
          em.getTransaction().begin();
          em.persist(t);
          em.getTransaction().commit();
      } catch (PersistenceException pex) {
          // Tratando a exceção e buscando a mensagem usando SELECT
          HandlingDBException hdbe = new HandlingDBException(new Mensagem(),
                  "findMensagemQuery", "constraint");
          System.out.println(">>>> Mensagem: "
                  + hdbe.getMessageFromDatabase(pex, em).getMessage());
          // Realizando log
          pex.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          // Fechar conexão
      }

  }
  ```

Mais detalhes estão no meu github.com/programadorthi.

Comment: Desconheço qualquer tipo de framework nesse sentido, @Ascension. Já vi tratamento de exceções por trecho de mensagem como você deseja, mas todos "feitos na unha" mesmo, nada pronto.

Comment: @LuizFernandoBueno valeu pela resposta. A questão é que tive que criar os fontes dos links acima e foi complicado. Se existisse um framework facilitaria o meu lado :D

Answer (score 2):

As restrições adicionadas ao banco de dados não devem ser a fonte primária da aplicação para as regras de validação, mas apenas uma garantia adicional.

Usando JPA, é possível usar a API Bean Validation com as anotações para validação de campos individuais. Por exemplo, um campo `NOT NULL` recebe a anotação [`@NotNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) com o atributo `message` para especificar a mensagem desejada. A mensagem pode, inclusive, pode ser internacionalizada em arquivos `.properties`.

Outra técnica usada é criar classes DAO genéricas que façam validações se, por exemplo, se o registro já existe antes da inclusão e se não existe antes da alteração e exclusão.

Enfim, de tudo o que tenho visto, a aplicação é quem deve tratar esses casos.

Mesmo quando falamos de dependência de registros para exclusão ou mesmo exclusão em cascata, os casos de uso devem prever esse tipo de possibilidade.

Comment: É isso mesmo, amigo, é uma das alternativas e ainda tem a possibilidade de internacionalização. Mas isso é um incremento!